# Why Shared Prefs don't persist in different Locale?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my app, the user can change the locale. I'm using SharedPreferences to save values ( which have to be in English so the language doesn't matter when it comes to them). The thing is whenever the locale is changed the SharedPreferences is empty (as if it wasn't set). I set a new value and end up having 2 different values depending the locale essentially. Now its not a major problem I tried looking around why it happens but couldn't find anything on the Doc's.

Comment: Are you sure this happens only when you change the locale? Do you commit/apply after every update to SharedPreferences.Editor?

Comment: Without the relevant code from your side, it's hard for us to figure out the problem.

Comment: Can you put your sharedPref code?